# What is the WindowProc of "MDI Client Window“ in MFC

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

guys ,
I am a new commer ,and I have just started to study MFC.
I have a question about the MDI application framework.
In MFC.
I leaned from the code that a ChildFrame is always created by MDI Client Window when I new a file.
But I can not find what's the WindowProc of "MDI Client Window“ in MFC.
Actually,"MDI Client Window“ is created after we create the Main Frame.

```
winmdi.cpp
 // Create MDICLIENT control with special IDC
 if ((m_hWndMDIClient = ::AfxCtxCreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, _T("mdiclient"), NULL,
      dwStyle, 0, 0, 0, 0, m_hWnd, (HMENU)AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST,
      AfxGetInstanceHandle(), (LPVOID)&ccs)) == NULL)
```

About the ["MDI Client Window“](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And while we are creating a ChildFrame ,we send a WM_MDICREATE message to "MDI Client Window“,and then we get the Handle of the Window.

```
    winmdi.cpp
    BOOL CMDIChildWnd::Create(LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
 LPCTSTR lpszWindowName, DWORD dwStyle,
 const RECT& rect, CMDIFrameWnd* pParentWnd,
 CCreateContext* pContext)

{
//......
 // create the window through the MDICLIENT window
 AfxHookWindowCreate(this);
 HWND hWnd = (HWND)::SendMessage(pParentWnd->m_hWndMDIClient,
      WM_MDICREATE, 0, (LPARAM)&mcs);
```

About the WM_MDICREATE ,I found this information from Microsoft.
*An application sends the WM_MDICREATE message to a multiple-document interface (MDI) client window to create an MDI child window.
If the message succeeds, the return value is the handle to the new child window.
If the message fails, the return value is NULL.*

I guess,perhaps Windows the WindowProc from AfxGetInstanceHandle();But to be honest,I do not really know how it does so.

AfxGetInstanceHandle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/36z3tfsb.aspx
This function allows you to retrieve the instance handle of the current application.

Please help me...
Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MFC there no special window procedure. All windows have one MFC internal window procedure called AfxWndProc. This procedure look into a message map that finally dispatches the window message to a handler.

Internally you will find nothing about a special MDI treatment in the window proc. Everything is done inside [CMDIFrameWnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30a87cxk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: While we are creating a MainFrame Window,we set the windowProc in WH_CBT hook.
==>_AfxCbtFilterHook(...) ,and you are right,it is AfxWndProc.
`code`BOOL CFrameWnd::Create(...)
{
//...
 AfxHookWindowCreate(this);
 HWND hWnd = ::AfxCtxCreateWindowEx(cs.dwExStyle, cs.lpszClass,
   cs.lpszName, cs.style, cs.x, cs.y, cs.cx, cs.cy,
   cs.hwndParent, cs.hMenu, cs.hInstance, cs.lpCreateParams);
}`code`

Comment: I wonder when do we set the WindowProc for ChildFrame.And I do not see any code which registers the Class for this window.
Does windows get WindowProc from Instance_Handle?  And do these window share a single Class?
::AfxCtxCreateWindowEx(, , , , , , , , , ,AfxGetInstanceHandle(),)

Comment: There is only one central class with one WIndowProc for all MFC Windows. The hook function creates the window and sets the handle into a map that is used to determine the associated CWnd object.